# is it possible to add tiers automatically in praat

Tags: praat

Is there a way to add tiers to Praat scripts automatically from the terminal? I want to iterate over thousands of files and add a second tier with a specific name and would prefer not to this manually.

Answer (score 0):

I needed a refresher on how to glob files in Praat, some code is from here:
http://praatscriptingtutorial.com/loopingThroughFiles

So update wd$ to the dir you want to loop inside of. It picks up all the *.TextGrid files, loops over them, adding an extra tier (in this case to bottom and named "blah"), then saves andremoves the TextGrid from your objects window. I'd recommend making a backup of your working directory before you run this, in case you don't like the exact behavior, or have it save as some new modified fileName$.

```
clearinfo
wd$ = "C:/Users/Nick/Desktop/praat/*.TextGrid"

downloadsList = Create Strings as file list: "downloadsList", wd$

selectObject: downloadsList

numFiles = Get number of strings
for fileNum from 1 to numFiles
    fileName$ = Get string: fileNum
    Read from file: fileName$
    Insert interval tier: 2, "blah"
    Save as text file: fileName$
    Remove
    selectObject: downloadsList
    printline Added for textgrid 'numFiles' 'fileName$'
endfor
Remove
```

Comment: I had tried something similar to this, but i need to select wav files at the same time. I have one tier already, with information in that I can't lose, so i don't want to make brand new tiers, i just want to add one, so i need to select wav files and text files together. I've tried selecting them in the terminal, and by writing plusObject into the praat script, but i havn't got it right yet.